# How to measure distance between object and mobile phone using camera?

Tags: optics, sensor

I am trying to determine the distance between object being photographed and the mobile camera which is capturing the photo. The only device that is used is mobile phone, can we get depth or distance value from sensors?

Comment: Is it possible to get the distance between an object and a mobile phone using sensors inside the mobile?

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65471/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143073/25301 etc

Comment: If you can take two images slightly offset from each other on the same plane, you can use something called parallax to get the distance to the object.